# How to maintain 2 branches in git which differ only in 1 commit

Tags: git

I have in git 2 branches, which contain following commits:

commits in branch a:

`A -> B -> C -> D -> ... -> N`

commits in branch b:

`A -> B -> X -> C -> D -> ... -> N`

The difference between branch `a` and `b` is that branch b contains one more commit, commit X. I want both branches stay the same except that commit X. So when now I commit something to branch `a`, I always have to cherry-pick it into branch `b`. Is there any smarter solution how to solve this issue in git? Because cherry-picking all the future commits I do not consider as a good idea.

Comment: I agree it's not a good idea to keep cherry picking; maybe you could expand on *why* you think you want this? What was the problem this seemed to solve?

Comment: Naming your commits with short letters is fine, but could you give slightly more informative branch names here, to help figure out your intended workflow? Also, if something is permanently different accross branches, maybe consider an ignore strategy. But you'd have to tell us more in any case.

Comment: commit X is a different login handling (I need to switch between them sometimes), codebase is not nice, so it is in multiple files across the project. I can easy solve it by creating config file, I was just interested if this can be solved by git.

Comment: You should absolutely solve that through configuration not version control.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is to move commit `X` to the head of branch `b`. In this case when branch `a` gets new commits in, you can simply do:

```
git checkout b
git rebase a
```

One obvious caveat though: you cannot rewrite the history in branch `a`. This assumes that you keep adding commits on top of `a`.

Comment: Either do that or just merge every time into the branch with commit X, which also expects you push general updates to the branch without X.
I'm guessing the author wanted to do that anyway, 1 branch general and 1 branch specific with commit X...